# Scroll View has ambiguous scrollable content height and width

Tags: xcode11, swift5

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scroll-view-layouts-with-interface-builder/).

I cannot get the scroller to work and I assume it has to do with my constrains error. I have a VC which I drag a Scroll View onto and stretch it to fit under the Navigation bar and touches left/right/bottom. I add the 4 constraints to the Scroll View all to View and not Safe View: top 88 and left/right/bottom to 0.

[image]

I apply the constraints and I get red lines all around the Scroll View and the error: Scroll View has ambiguous scrollable content height and width.

[image]

If I ignore this error and continue with the tutorial, the scroll function doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You may have already answered your own question here as I have tried to replicate the problem and get no issues when I constrain to the safe area instead of the view.

Alternatively, you could try centring the X and the Y position within its container, which isn't as good a solution to the problem but will likely remove the ambiguity.

[image]

Comment: `get no issues when I constrain to the safe area instead of the view.` remove it because it is doesn't have influence on the problem